# Microsoft mouse and keyboard centre all wrong

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse

I have a MS Laser Mouse 5000 and Comfort Curve Keyboard 3000. I recently upgraded to W10 and just downloaded Microsoft mouse and keyboard centre.

Firstly, it detects I have a totally different keyboard than the one I have plugged in.

Secondly, it only shows me the keyboard settings not the mouse ones, even when I launch it from the Control Panel "mouse" section.

Is there a way I can do a clean reset of the mouse/keyboard I am using?

Comment: Do the keyboard and mouse work without the software in question?

Comment: According to the MS [product support](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/wireless-laser-mouse-5000) page for your mouse it looks like it isn't supported on Win10. I suspect it is using a standard generic driver to give you the basic functionality. I haven't checked your keyboard but I suspect that is a similar issue.